# ASP Running on CentOS with Nginx

Tags: asp-classic, nginx, centos6

I'm running a VPS with CentOS 6 installed, also installed is Nginx and PHP5-FPM. I've taken over a very old project that has some asp classic code inside some .shtml files. I have an issue with this, everything is working fine on the old server, but part of the project requirement is to move everything over to a new server (which I've setup). On this new server, the ASP code is not running.

Now, the one option I have is to rewrite all the ASP code into PHP, but it's honestly not an option I really want to do. This is all volunteer work, and I'm already working on writing a brand new project to replace this old one for them, so I didn't want to change the old one as well.

I'm wondering if someone can provide some easy to follow step by step instructions to get classic asp code working on my setup. Please keep in mind that I'm new to running my own VPS if possible.

Comment: Are you sure it's Classic ASP as they would usually have a .asp extension, not .shtml?

Comment: Yea, I'm absolutely positive that it's Classic ASP, I thought it was weird myself, but it's not like I wrote this project, I'm writing the replacement, I just want to get this one working on the new server for the next couple months.

Comment: If you rename one script to test as .asp does it work? When you say it doesn't work what happens? Any errors?

Comment: If I rename a page to *.asp, it just tries to download it, which is kind of expected for something it doesn't know how to process. As far as errors, there are none, it just doesn't output the ASP code, the HTML within the file outputs fine.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://asp2php.naken.cc/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache has something called apache::asp for native/clasic ASP code - http://www.apache-asp.org/

If it's ASP.NET then you need to run mono:
http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono

There are also a few similar questions here on stackoverflow, for the actual installation steps you can refer to http://www.apache-asp.org/install.html

Comment: I stated that I'm running Nginx (ie. not Apache), and that it is for ASP Classic.